# Multiple Select with Explode: only returns the word "Array"

Tags: php, wordpress, select, explode

Using Wordpress I have created a multiple select box so that users can select categories to exclude. When the page initially loads I see my default values pre-selected. However when I select new values and save... I only see the word "Array" echoed and nothing selected?

```
<select class="amultiple" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"  name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>[]" multiple="multiple" size="8">
            <?php 
                global $options;
                    foreach ($options as $value) {
                        if (get_settings( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) { $$value['id'] = $value['std']; } else { $$value['id'] = get_settings( $value['id'] ); 
                        }
                    }
                    $categories = &get_categories('type=post&orderby=name&hide_empty=1');
                    if ($categories) {
                        $ex_cat = implode(',', $tt_cat_exclude);

                        foreach ($categories as $category) {
                            $selected = (in_array($ex_cat, $category->cat_ID)) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
                            echo '<option value="' . $category->cat_ID . '"' . $selected . '>' . $category->cat_name . '</option>' . "\n";
                        }
                    }
?>
</select>
<br />For testing purposes, print variables: <?php echo $ex_cat; ?>
```

http://i48.tinypic.com/k9e3qq.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `implode()`

Like so

```
$ex_cat = implode(',', $tt_cat_exclude);
```

This will return a comma separated list

This line should be

```
$selected = (in_array($category->cat_ID, $ex_cat)) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
```

Changed to

```
$selected = (in_array($category->cat_ID, $tt_cat_exclude)) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
```

Since the `$ex_cat` is a string and cannot be used in in_array()

The `$ex_cat` is now redundant i guess.

Comment: well, the word "array" isn't printing...now random numbers are :)

Comment: Ok, that is work - however it's not "remembering" the selections (the variables are still printed, but nothing is selected in the box) 

I'm sooo close!!

Comment: Does that mean that the "current" or "selected" category is not selected in the select box?

Comment: I think you are comparing the key to the value

Comment: exactly, what the user has selected isn't selected (although I still see the variables printed below the form)

Comment: Here is a screen shot: http://i48.tinypic.com/k9e3qq.gif (Blog & Business are what I selected, categories 3 & 4 respectively)

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't really paying attention to what you were trying to do. I changed my answer accordingly

Comment: Any idea how I'd get $ex_cat onto another page? :)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. But i suppose you have to save it somewhere, like a file, database, session, cookie or something. It all depends what you want it for.

Comment: Well now I need to take the selected "excluded categories" and pass them onto a whole new page (navigation.php) where $ex_cat will be printed in a query string (&sort=name&exclude=$ex_cat) since $ex_cat is not a 'global option' I'm not sure how to pull it. I probably need to write it to the DB first. Just not sure how...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `tt_cat_exclude` is missing it's opening `$`

Answer (score 1):

name="tt_cat_exclude[]" means you're defining an array, so it's normal for the output to be "array"

for testing try print_r (outputs the whole architecture of the variable)
or var_dump (outputs the var type too)

Answer (score 0):

When you postback, the field `tt_cat_exclude` is an array of the values that you've set - because you've name it `tt_cat_exclude[]` with a `[]` behind.

Example:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<select class="amultiple" id="tt_cat_exclude"  name="tt_cat_exclude[]" multiple="multiple" size="8">
  <option value="1">TestingA</option>
  <option value="2">TestingB</option>
  <option value="3">TestingC</option>
  <option value="4">TestingD</option>
  <option value="5">TestingE</option>
 </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<br/><br/>For testing purposes: <?php

if(isset($_POST['tt_cat_exclude'])){
  var_dump($_POST['tt_cat_exclude']); // outputs an array of the selected values
}

?>
```